# Is $h^{0,k}$ a topological invariant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, coherent-cohomology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $X(\mathbb{C})$ is homeomorphic to $Y(\mathbb{C})$. Is it true that $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} H^k(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=\dim_{\mathbb{C}} H^k(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ for $k\ge 2$? (Note that for $k=1$ it follows by Hodge theory).

Comment: An answer is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279837/dolbeault-cohomology-is-invariant-under-homeomorphisms/290877#290877).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is *no*.

There are counterexamples already for surfaces, due to X. Gang and F. Campana (unpublished). The link to Campana's article is [here](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Pierre-Yves.Gaillard/DIVERS/hodgenumbers.pdf), and the relevant result is

> **Proposition 0.1** Il existe des surfaces projectives complexes $S$, $S_0$ simplement connexes et de type général homéomorphes, mais ayant des nombres de Hodge différents.

You can look at this paper and at the references cited therein for further details.